# Binding lost on validatedObservable after update

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have an observable object that needs to be updated after saving to the server. When I reload the observable it causes the `validatedObservable` to stop working. How can I keep the `validatedObservable` working after updating the observable it was referencing?

In my test example, if click the Save button initially it will display the error next tot he textbox and the summary error message below.

Fill in the textbox and click save. The binding for the summary error message no longer works.

http://jsfiddle.net/abJHj/

```
<div data-bind="with: person">
    Id <span data-bind="text: id">0</span><br />
    Name <input data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'input'" value="." placeholder="new person name" /><br/>
    Modified Date <span data-bind="text: modifiedDate">0</span><br/>    
</div>
<p><span data-bind="visible: allErrors().isAnyMessageShown()">We have errors!</span></p>
<button data-bind="click: saveAndReloadPerson">Save And Reload Person</button>
<p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></p>


ko.validation.init({
    grouping: { deep: true, observable: true, live: true }
});

function Person(person) {
    var self = this;
    person = person || {};

    self.id = ko.observable(person.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(person.name).extend({ required: { params: true, message: "Name required" }});
    self.modifiedDate = ko.observable(person.modifiedDate);
}

function VM(data) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};

    self.person = ko.observable(new Person(data));

    self.allErrors = ko.validatedObservable({
        person: self.person
    });

    self.saveAndReloadPerson = function () {
        debugger;
        if(self.allErrors.isValid()){
            self.person(new Person({ id: 1, name: "Tom", modifiedDate: new Date() }));
        }
        else{
            self.allErrors().errors.showAllMessages()
        }
    };

}

var vm = new VM({ id: 0, name: "" });
ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-hydrating the `self.person` observable with a `new Person` you could update the individual properties instead.

Of course that might have other implications if there is more to your app then is show here, but it seems perfectly reasonable for what you have shown in your question.

UPDATE: You could also make the validation specific to each person like this:

```
function Person(person) {
    var self = this;

    // ...

    self.allErrors = ko.validatedObservable(self);
}
```

and have the `VM` compute `allErrors` based on the current person. Note: You'll probably need to check for nulls.

```
function VM(data) {
    var self = this;

    // ...

    self.allErrors = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.person().allErrors();
    });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is an option. Sometimes it's an array of items, and in cases where it's a new item, there is no key or id to match to make sure you are updating the right item. Also, it's pretty tedious to manually update each property.

Comment: Well, that's a horse of a different color. I've updated my answer to reflect the new info you provided.